# Does the CommandArgument (used with ASP.NET Repeater) need validation?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Can the `CommandArgument` supplied to the `ItemCommand` event via `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` be faked by the client?

In the code base I'm working on, this holds the ID of an entry to delete - which may or may not belong to the logged in user. I'm wondering whether this value needs validation before performing the deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CommandArgument is not found in html or posted back as plain text as input values are, but it is part of the ViewState (which is stored in a hidden field). If you don't encrypt the ViewState, or if someone can decrypt it, it can be manipulated.

See one of these links for more info about forcing ViewState encryption:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx (.NET2)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#SecuringViewState (.NET4)